# Send an email Java - tutorial problem

Tags: java, properties, jakarta-mail

I am [trying this example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=144) to send an email using java.

I need to know where in the code does it make use of the properties of the property file. (shown in the example) ? and, Where it has been refereed in the code ?

**NOTE:
And also, what are the values that i should replace in the property file, If i'm going to use the Google SMTP ?**

```
            import java.util.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import javax.mail.*;
            import javax.mail.internet.*;

             /**
            * Simple demonstration of using the javax.mail API.
            *
        * Run from the command line. Please edit the implementation
        * to use correct email addresses and host name.
        */
        public final class Emailer {

          public static void main( String... aArguments ){
            Emailer emailer = new Emailer();
            //the domains of these email addresses should be valid,
            //or the example will fail:
            emailer.sendEmail(
              "fromblah@blah.com", "toblah@blah.com",
               "Testing 1-2-3", "blah blah blah"
            );
           }

          /**
          * Send a single email.
          */
          public void sendEmail(
            String aFromEmailAddr, String aToEmailAddr,
            String aSubject, String aBody
          ){
            //Here, no Authenticator argument is used (it is null).
            //Authenticators are used to prompt the user for user
            //name and password.
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance( fMailServerConfig, null );
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage( session );
            try {
              //the "from" address may be set in code, or set in the
              //config file under "mail.from" ; here, the latter style is used
              //message.setFrom( new InternetAddress(aFromEmailAddr) );
              message.addRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(aToEmailAddr)
              );
              message.setSubject( aSubject );
              message.setText( aBody );
              Transport.send( message );
            }
            catch (MessagingException ex){
              System.err.println("Cannot send email. " + ex);
            }
          }

          /**
          * Allows the config to be refreshed at runtime, instead of
          * requiring a restart.
          */
          public static void refreshConfig() {
            fMailServerConfig.clear();
            fetchConfig();
          }

          // PRIVATE //

          private static Properties fMailServerConfig = new Properties();

          static {
            fetchConfig();
          }

          /**
          * Open a specific text file containing mail server
          * parameters, and populate a corresponding Properties object.
          */
          private static void fetchConfig() {
            InputStream input = null;
            try {
              //If possible, one should try to avoid hard-coding a path in this
              //manner; in a web application, one should place such a file in
              //WEB-INF, and access it using ServletContext.getResourceAsStream.
              //Another alternative is Class.getResourceAsStream.
              //This file contains the javax.mail config properties mentioned above.
              input = new FileInputStream( "C:\\Temp\\MyMailServer.txt" );
              fMailServerConfig.load( input );
            }
            catch ( IOException ex ){
              System.err.println("Cannot open and load mail server properties file.");
            }
            finally {
              try {
                if ( input != null ) input.close();
              }
              catch ( IOException ex ){
                System.err.println( "Cannot close mail server properties file." );
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Show us what you are trying. Don't just provide a link to source.

Comment: Its the same code, anyway i'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

When the class is first loaded, the code inside the [static initializer block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#39245) executed.

```
static {
   fetchConfig();
}
```

You'll see that calls the `fetchConfig()` method which then loads the `fMailServerConfig` properties.

```
private static Properties fMailServerConfig = new Properties();

private static void fetchConfig() {
   // ...[omitted stuff]...
   input = new FileInputStream( "C:\\Temp\\MyMailServer.txt" );
   fMailServerConfig.load( input );
   // ...[omitted stuff]...
}
```

Notice that the `fetchConfig()` method is `static` -- it's called from the static initializer so it needs to be static as there isn't really an instance of the class yet.  Also, we'd probably use the same configuration for all instances so there's no need for each instance to have its own config.

Also note that the method is `private` because we wouldn't want the method to be called from anywhere else.

The `javax.mail` package will know what properties to use. i.e., `mail.host`, `mail.from`, etc. ([javax.mail documentation here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/package-summary.html))

**A Note On Using Google Gmail for SMTP**

Due to security, it might get a bit tricky to use Google's SMTP server. How would Google know you're not just some spammer using them as a relay?  You'll likely have to authenticate with them first -- they have [example code for using Google Gmail APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/code.html) you could read and use, but this goes beyond the vanilla `javax.mail` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void fetchConfig() {
```

opens a FileInputStream that loads data into `fMailServerConfig` which is defined as:

```
  private static Properties fMailServerConfig = new Properties();
```

The properties class is responsible for reading this.  It generates a message with this code:

```
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance( fMailServerConfig, null );
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage( session );
```

As to the specifics of `Properties`, I can't say what the purpose is.  Perhaps there is more code provided for the example.  Is `Properties` a Java framework class?

Comment: according to the author of the tutorial we only need to add the j2ee.jar to our class path and everything else should work. :S

In this example the author has made use of a TXT file to store the properties which is needed to send the mail. But, i need to use a `property file` for this. how should i do this ?

Comment: What makes you think that you need a .property file? The properties are read from the .txt file here.

Comment: Yes it's read from a TXT file, but i require it to be read from a property file.

Comment: Just rename the file to .properties and change the line that reads it to read the new file. The format of this .txt file is the same like the format of .properties files. You could use Netbeans to maintain it then.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust this line in **fetchConfig()** to load your settings:

```
input = new FileInputStream( "C:\\Temp\\MyMailServer.txt" );
```

Read this [google configuration web page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) for the second question...

Something along these lines works for me:

```
mail.transport.protocol   = smtps
mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
mail.smtps.port           = 465
mail.smtps.host           = smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtps.auth           = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it without property file. My below code works perfect. Use it

Just call this function to send automated email to client. 
In parameter "to" is email address to which you want to send an email.

I usually do it in Maven project. If you are using maven project then import the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

For attaching pdf refer **https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm**

```
private void sendMail(String to, String subject, String emailBody) throws MessagingException{
    final String username = "youremail@gmail.com";
    final String password = "emailPassword";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("shubham20.yeole@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if 2-way authentication is enabled on your gmail account ?